# Compactness of $[0,\,1)$ in a certain metric $\rho$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I was asked to prove that $Y \doteq \left([0,\,1),\,\rho\right)$, in which $\rho \colon [0,\,1) \times [0,\,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $\rho(x,\,y) \doteq \min\left\{\left|x - y \right|,\,1 - \left|x - y \right|\right\}$, is a compact metric space, by constructing a continuous surjective map between $X = \left([0,\,1],\,d\right)$ (usual metric, $d(x,\,y) = \left|x - y \right|$) and $Y$, but I'm not sure how to obtain this surjection. Maybe using something like sequential compactness makes it easier?

Anyway, any tips on how to find this surjection? Or any other valid approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like what did you try?

Comment: You also need your map to be continuous to get homeomorphism (Though I know some people include that in the definition of the word "map", others don't)

Comment: $f(x)=x$ for $x<1$ and $f(1)=0$ does the job.

Comment: This metric space is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.  It is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  the question doesn't say anything about homeomorphisms. $S^1$ is a continuous image of $[0, 1]$.

Comment: The objective of the question is to prove that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and it's one of the itens of the full problem.

Comment: Hint: think about what the mapping $x \mapsto e^{2\pi x}$ does to the half-open interval $[0, 1)$ and the closed interval $[0, 1]$. Don't worry about compactness, just try to understand the geometry and what happens to neighbourhoods of $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan I know.  Alan made a comment about homeomorphism.